# Import Timestamp into MySQL Table and convert the date

Tags: php, html, mysql, csv, timestamp

I'm trying to load a csv into my MySQL Table.

The format of the CSV is (i am skipping 2 lines, i just shortened the csv to make it better readable)

```
|d07datum           |d07stunde|d07tty  |d07bg |d07vorgang|d07sig                         |d07zweig|d07mtyp|d07geb              |d07lvke|d07kopie|d07syst|d07gebdat          |d07plz  |d07sex|d07abtlg|d07heimatzw|d07loeschgrund|d07busaktion|d07tour|d07aort|d07timestamp            
|Apr 23 2012 12:00AM|       23|hwrsisis|     0|         9|                               |       0|      0|            0.000000|      0|        |      0|Jan  1 1753 12:00AM|        |      |       0|          0|             0|           0|      0|      0|23.04.2012 23:09:02:728
```

My Load Data Statement is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$_FILES['datei']['tmp_name']}'
INTO TABLE `tbl_daten` 
ENCLOSED BY '|' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 2 LINES 
(@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, d07bg, d07vorgang, d07sig, @dummy, @dummy, d07geb, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, d07sex, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @datestamp)
SET d07timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@datestamp, '%d-%b-%y %H:%i:%s' )"
```

I Load the file via an Upload form into my PHP Script, where my Query is this LOAD DATA Statement. It works fine with the values except the d07timestamp (the last column).

The Format is 23.04.2012 23:09:02:728, but I need it to match the timestamp form of mysql, like 2012-02-15 05:35:45.

I have no idea what stops this from working.

Just to be complete, i post my whole scripts.

upload.html

```
<html>

<form action="parsing.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

parsing.php

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("db_data", $con);

if ($db->connect_errno)
{
    echo 'No Connetion';
    echo 'Error: (' . $db->connect_errno . ') ' . $db->connect_error;
    exit;
}

$sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '{$_FILES['datei']['tmp_name']}'
        INTO TABLE `tbl_data` 
        ENCLOSED BY '|' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
        IGNORE 2 LINES 
        (@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, d07bg, d07vorgang, d07sig, @dummy, @dummy, d07geb, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, d07sex, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @datestamp)
        SET d07timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@datestamp, '%d-%b-%y  %H:%i:%s'' )";

$db->query($sql);

?>
```

I'm running now

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Path to CSV'
INTO TABLE `tbl_daten`
FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 2 LINES 
(@dummy, @dummy, @dummy, d07bg, d07vorgang, d07sig, @dummy, @dummy, d07geb, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, d07sex, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @dummy, @datestamp)
SET d07timestamp = STR_TO_DATE(@datestamp, '%d-%b-%y  %H:%i:%s' )
```

It proceed with no errors at all, but also no inserted fields. I'm starting to get nuts!

Comment: What's not working? The `LOAD` query aborts? You get invalid dates in the d07timestamp field? Incorrect/malformed dates?

Comment: It seems like there is an syntax error in the load query. I put this directly into phpmyadmin to see if this works and the result is #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ENCLOSED BY '|' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (@dummy, @dummy,' at line 3

Comment: That means the syntax error occurred AT or immediately BEFORE `ENCLOSED`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html. In this case, it should be `FIELDS ENCLOSED BY ...`.